# Using the DbContext from an MVC project in a C# Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, dbcontext

I have two projects in my solution. The first is an MVC project called EXSIS and the second is a C# Windows Forms Application called Backend. EXSIS contains the database file exsisDB.mdf and was built using the database first method. Now what I want to be able to do is access EXSIS's DbContext (called exsisDBEntities) within Backend in order to add records to my database at a particular time every day. I have added EXSIS as a reference to Backend.

Here is the code for Form1 in Backend:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EXSIS.Models;

namespace Backend
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    exsisDBEntities db = new exsisDBEntities();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.TimerCallback callback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(ProcessTimerEvent);

        var dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 1, 0, 0);

        if (DateTime.Now < dt)
        {
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, dt - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        }
    }

    private void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)
    {
        LastOrder();
    }

    private void LastOrder()
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        customers = db.Customers.ToList();
        foreach (Customer customer in db.Customers)
        {
            DateTime LastOrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(customer.Transactions.Last().Date);
            TimeSpan TimeSinceLastOrder = DateTime.Now - LastOrderDate;
            if (TimeSinceLastOrder.TotalDays > 30)
            {
                Notification n = new Notification();
                n.NotificationID = db.Notifications.Last().NotificationID + 1;
                n.DateGenerated = DateTime.Now;
                n.NotificationType = "Last Order";
                n.CustID = customer.CustID;

                NotificationLink nl = new NotificationLink();
                nl.NotificationLinkID = db.NotificationLinks.Last().NotificationLinkID + 1;
                nl.NotificationID = n.NotificationID;
                nl.RepID = customer.RepID;

                db.Notifications.Add(n);
                db.NotificationLinks.Add(nl);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

When I ran this I originally got an error saying:

> No connection string named 'exsisDBEntities' could be found in the application config file.

So I went to the web.config file in EXSIS and copied the following connection string across to the app.config file in Backend:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="exsisDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EXSISModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EXSISModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EXSISModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\exsisDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But that just gave me a new error. When the following line in the the LastOrder() method runs:

```
customers = db.Customers.ToList();
```

I get the error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Any help with how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Consider moving the data access (Entity Framework) code out of your MVC project and into a new "Data" project.
2. Can you successfully access the database from your MVC project?

Comment: look at the repository pattern

Comment: @Jonesy: First off, that comment is unrelated to the question; Second off, EF follows the repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the *.edmx file from the other project. The `metadata=res://...` connection string is a reference to the edmx file *and* the database. Both are required in a database-first generate context.

However, as @TroyCarlson noted, you're better off moving all this off into a class library that both projects can reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem , but I can't solve it yet but "using" might be useful:

```
using(exsisDBEntities db = new exsisDBEntities())
{
     //your code
}
```